# About images of (prime) ideals under injective endomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $f : R \to R$ be an injective unitary endomorphism of a commutative ring with 1.
Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$.
I have several related questions concerning the image of $I$ under $f$:

1) Under which condition is $f(I)$ already an ideal of $R$ (i.e. when do we have $f(I) = f(I) R$)?

Certainly this is true if $f$ is surjective (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416709/must-an-ideal-contain-the-kernel-for-its-image-to-be-an-ideal) for instance). Is this condition also necessary?

2) Suppose furthermore that $I$ is prime. Under which condition is $f(I)$ a prime ideal?

A partial answer is given for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292829/a-proof-that-shows-surjective-homomorphic-image-of-prime-ideal-is-prime) (the image of prime ideal under a surjective homomorphism is a prime ideal). But I am particularly interested in the situation where the homomorphism is not surjective.

3) Suppose that $I$ is a minimal prime ideal and that $f^{-1}(I) = I$.
Under which condition does $f(I) = I$ (or at least $f(I) R = I$) hold?

For (possibly non-minimal) prime ideals this does not hold. But I cannot think of a counterexample of a minimal prime ideal.

One always has $f(I) \subseteq I$.

4) Is there a geometric interpretation of these conditions? (The interpretation of the extension of an ideal was discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866577/the-geometric-interpretation-for-extension-of-ideals)).

Comment: The questions are too general to have good answers and indicate that you haven't looked at a single example before asking. Better do that and then ask a better or more focussed question. It also seems to me that you actually are interested in something else, and this seems to be only the preparation for it.